# MongoDB $maxDistance is working but $minDistance will not

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I am trying to find the data from my collection and display in the order of nearest to furthest from a geoJSON point based on the location(loc:) of the post when it was created.

I have gone into the mongo console and ran

```
db.my-collection.createIndex( { loc : "2dsphere" } )
```

in order to make sure they are being indexed as 2dsphere.

Now whenever I user my find command to list the posts in the order mentioned above only the $maxDistance works while the $minDistance has no effect at all on how they are ordered. Here is the code:

```
return posts.find({
        loc:
             { $near :
                    {
                        $geometry:{ type:"Point", coordinates:[ lng, lat]},
                        $maxDistance: maxDistance,
                        $minDistance: minDistance
                    }
             },
        });

}
```

I believe I have done everything as described on mongoDB(http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/near/) but it appears I am missing something.

Comment: I don't understand. If you are trying to order them, then you need to specify a `sort` option. Your use of `maxDistance` and `minDistance` is a hard constraint (don't show any results not meeting these criteria), not a sort order.

Comment: the $near command automatically sorts them if I am not mistaken. The problem is when it sorts them it is not taking into account the $minDistance away a post needs to be in order for it to show up so they all end up showing up.

Comment: do you get the same result when you execute the query directly in mongodb? i.e., is this a meteor question or a mongo question?

Comment: Whenever I try to run the command in the mongo db console I get this error "$near requires a point, given { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ 100.0, 100.0 ] }"

Comment: I am unsure if it is something going on with Meteor or with mongo. I think it may be something with mongo because if I edit the max distance in the code the posts will change(for example $maxDistance = 0 will make none of the posts load) but editing the $minDistance does nothing.

Comment: Valid longitudes are between +180 and -180. Valid latitudes are between +90 and -90. So 100, 100 is invalid.

Comment: After running it in the mongo console with proper lng and lat values nothing appears to happen. Should it be printing out something when I run the find command in the mongo console?

Comment: It should show results, or at least an empty array if there are no results.

Comment: it doesn't print out anything when I run it. :/ so does this mean it is something with mongo?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get both the $minDistance & $maxDistance to work I had to add the following line to the code:

```
Collection._ensureIndex({'loc':'2dsphere'});
```

Comment: @lsaac  even with indexing of '2dsphere' still I am not getting the results ?